# How do I loop through an array composed of object and call back a specific objects value? JavaScript/Callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback, for-in-loop

I'm crazy new to JavaScript. I've only been doing if for less than a month, so please excuse me...

I'm given an array of 3 different objects. I need to make it so that the console.log at the bottom will return as expected. i.e. When the array 'users' is passed through a for loop, it will search for the string value '16t', and find the object that has that value, and display the information correctly

This is what I have so far:

```
var users = function(arr, callback) {
 for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    var obj = arr[ i ];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) === '16t'){
            callback(obj[prop]);
        }
    }
  }
 };
```

---

This is the problem:

```
var users = [
  {
    id: '12d',
    email: 'tyler@gmail.com',
    name: 'Tyler',
    address: '167 East 500 North'
  },
  {
    id: '15a',
    email: 'cahlan@gmail.com',
    name: 'Cahlan',
    address: '135 East 320 North'
  },
  {
    id: '16t',
    email: 'ryan@gmail.com',
    name: 'Ryan',
    address: '192 East 32 North'
  },
];

getUserById(users, '16t', function(user){
    console.log('The user with the id 16t has the email of ' + user.email + ' the name of ' + user.name + ' and the address of ' + user.address);
});
```

Comment: So what did you try? Sounds like you want us to do your homework.

Comment: Josh's filter answer is the more "experienced" way to program it.  But, for a simple start, you should look at using  `users.forEach(function(aUser) { test aUser.id here} );`

Comment: Please do not deface your posts. By posting them here you made it free to read for everyone and by defacing it you take away the effort the answerer put into their answer to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just filter for that user:

```
function getUserById(users, id, callback) {
  return callback(users.filter(function(user) {
    return user.id === id;
  })[0]);
}

getUserById(users, '16t', function(user){
  console.log('The user with the id ' + user.id + ' has the email of ' + user.email + ' the name of ' + user.name + ' and the address of ' + user.address);
});
```

## edit

[lodash _.find](https://lodash.com/docs#find) also does this for you:

```
function getUserById(users, id, callback) {
  return callback(_.find(users, function(user) {
    return user.id === id;
  }));
}
```

You can look at their source code on [line 7,570](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L7570) to see how they handle optimization.

Comment: filter seems like a waste if there is just one match since you keep loping when you do not. And if there is no match it would throw an error.

Comment: @epascarello yes error handling and stopping on a single match would be an additional feature to make this function more robust, but conceptually and semantically, filtering through a collection is correct.